# How do I use the Python module "keyboardleds" to determine Caps Lock state?

Tags: python, capslock

1. I want my system to ascertain the state of Caps Lock (is it on or off) by
   inspecting the keyboard DIRECTLY. After much searching, I understand that this
   can be done in Python by using the module "keyboardleds".

   I'm not familiar with Python, **so my main request is, can you tell me how to
   use the module keyboardleds in a Python script, so that it tells me what the
   state of Caps Lock is?** The Python version on my system is 2.7.3rc2.
2. The information I've found about "keyboardleds", is too technical for me to
   understand. Also an example I found of how keyboardleds is used, uses complex
   python programming that I don't understand either. Also, the example I've looked
   at uses keyboardleds for one of its **other** purposes, not for the purpose I want
   (ie determining the state of Caps Lock).

   I don't even know what the "import" commands mean at the beginning of the
   example script, and whether I need all of them.

   **I would be most grateful if you could tell me what python commands I need to
   use, and what detailed contents I put in them.**
3. I just need the python script to give an exit status of zero (true) if Caps
   Lock is off, and an exit status of 1 (false) if Caps Lock is on.

   Say the python script is called "capslockstate". Then I'll use it in a bash script as follows:

   ```
    if capslockstate
    then
       <perform an action based on the fact that Caps Lock is off>
    else
       <perform an action based on the fact that Caps Lock is on>
    fi
   ```
4. SIGNIFICANT I BELIEVE:

   Regarding accessing the keyboard, the info I've found refers to using either `/dev/console`, `/dev/input/event*`, and `/dev/input/by-path/*-event-kbd`. On my system, all 3 of these exist. In the latter 2 cases, I've got the following on my system:

   ```
    /dev/input/event0 through to /dev/input/event9.

    /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd   
    ### ie only ^this^ one item exists
   ```

   The "by-path" is the **actual** directory name.

   I believe that one of the above 2 "/dev/input/..." entities is what I need to use (as opposed to `/dev/console`), even though I don't understand the ins and outs of it.
5. Below are the websites where I found the information on keyboardleds:

   1. The first site that put me onto using keyboardleds (with examples that are too complex for me):

      [Alternative approaches for accessing keyboard LEDs in Linux with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625367/alternative-approaches-for-accessing-keyboard-leds-in-linux-with-python)

      What particularly interested me on this site is the comment "the program [keyboardleds] accesses the keyboard DIRECTLY."
   2. Official documentation I believe, on keyboardleds (too complex for me to understand):

      [python-keyboardleds 0.3.3 documentation](https://python-keyboardleds.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.3/)
   3. The site of the author of keyboardleds:

      [python-keyboardleds — Jakub Wilk's software](http://jwilk.net/software/python-keyboardleds)

Comment: why python...? if it is a linux system with the basic `util-linux` package installed, then you probably want `setleds`.

Comment: Please log in properly. If you're having problems with that, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/account)

Answer (score -1):

I have been having good luck using:

```
from win32con import VK_CAPITAL
if GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 1:
    print ("CAPS Lock is on.")
elif GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 0:
    print ("CAPS Lock is off.")
```

This is on a windows computer with Python3, so not 100% sure if it works on linux also, but worth noting as an option for those needing to do this on windows, this works for sure in that case - I've seen it myself.

Randy

Comment: As the module names suggest, `win32api` and `win32con` are Windows exclusive and are not available on *NIX. I do think, however, the answer gives a good insight into how that is done on other operation systems.